# How can I find Azure DevOps projects using my extension installed at org level

Tags: azure-devops

I am managing an Azure DevOps organization where i have more then 500 projects. I have installed 100+ extension from marketplace in last 3 years. Now i want to remove extension which are not/less used by projects. I want to know if there is any way to get the extension Vs projects reports who is using these extension so that i can see which are being used and which are not and take decision to keep or delete.

Appreciate your response

Thanks
Den

Comment: This question should be directed at Azure DevOps Services support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I find Azure DevOps projects using my extension installed at org level

I am afraid there is such a way to find out the projects using the extension.

**As a workaround**, you could check the **History** for each extension. If this extension is used very low or left for a long time, then you can consider removing them:

For example, I just only used this extension **once** a long time ago (`2 Dec 2019`) after I installed it:

[image]

So I can decide to delete this extension based on this information.

**Note:**

To be safe, I suggest you make a backup before removing the extension.